# File has moved to other folder. But I can't rename it in spyder

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, shutil

```
import os
import shutil
src_folder = r"C:\new1\\"
dst_folder = r"C:\new2\\"
file_name = 'testword.docx'
if os.path.exists(dst_folder + file_name):
    data = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    only_name = data[0]
    extension = data[1]
    new_base = only_name + 'Renamed' + extension
    new_name = os.path.join(dst_folder, new_base)
    shutil.move(src_folder + file_name, new_name)
else:
    shutil.move(src_folder + file_name, dst_folder + file_name)
```

I was trying to write a code to move a file from one folder to another and rename it. The file is moving to another folder, But I can't rename it. I am doing this using python(spyder). Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Why can't you rename it?  What happens?

Comment: I am not getting any errors but the file named testword.docx is moving from folder new1 to new2 with the same name. Here in the code I have used the word renamed to add it to testword.docx. So when the file is moving from new1 to new2 it should change to testwordRenamed.docx. But it is moving with same name testword.docx.

Thank you

Comment: It should only have "renamed" added if `testword.docx` already exists in the new folder. If it doesn't, then it gets moved as is. That's what your code says.